# How to delete To-One and To-Many relationship to same entity with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have two Core Data entities: Asset and Image. An Asset has both, a To-Many and a To-One relationship to Image. See diagram:

[image: To-Many and To-One relationship]

For the domain, if an image is deleted from `images`, this image can no longer be the `keyImage`.

Can i enforce this by using the right inverse relationships and delete rules in Core Data, or do i have to make a subclass of `NSManagedObject` for Asset and add a custom `removeImage` method, that sets `keyImage` to nil, if an image, that is also `keyImage`, is removed from `images`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. All of your relationships have inverses and you should specify the deletion rule to handle what happens to the relationship when an item is deleted.

So, once you have the inverse from `Image` to `keyImage` and an item which is a `keyImage` is deleted it will automatically set the `keyImage` relationship to `nil`. The exact same process can be used to remove the image from `images`.

Note that deleting an `Image` item from the `images` relationship doesn't remove it from the context. You need to explicitly call `deleteObject:` on the context with the target item to do that (and then the deletion rules will run on its relationships).

The complexity comes if some other image needs to be automatically selected as the key image, then you will need custom code in your subclass.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to give reverse relationships to both relationships and i set all four delete rules to „nullify“ — but when i removed an image (that was also keyImage) from images, it just stayed keyImage. What are the correct delete rules?

Comment: Your rules are correct. I'd say the issue is that you aren't actually deleting from the context, just the relationship...